# Can Puerto Rican niceties be compared to Southern Hospitality?

Tags: comparación-de-idiomas, puerto-rico

How do we interpret/translate the niceties of PR Spanish?

Puerto Rican Spanish contains niceties such as "mi amor." For example, a lady asking a person for a favor and saying "Gracias, mi amor." Do you interpret as "thank you, darling!" or simply "thank you!"

Can it be compared to the English southern hospitality "bless her heart," "what a darling," etc. ?

What is the best way to interpret niceties, whether to do it literally, since they don't necessarily mean to say "darling" but rather demonstrate they are being polite or respectful? or maybe just out of habit, since it is such a big part of the culture.

Comment: Note that in the southern vernacular "bless her heart" can be interpreted as the opposite of a "nicety" depending on context.

Answer (score 1):

i would interpret it as just "thank you" and of course depending on the girl i might remember what nicetie she used the last time if she gets to thanks me again for something.

don't interpret it literally they are just beign polite, and choose english niceties carefully if you translate them, specially those with mami, mamita, etc

"gracias mi amor" means kind of "thanks sweetie"

all niceties for sure mean nice to see you